# Excel - Transposing unsorted items

Tags: excel, excel-formula, transpose, vba

So lets say that I have a table like this..

`TID    Person  Type    Name
 1      Andy     F     Orange
 2      Andy     M     Beef
 3      Andy     V     Carrot
 4      Andy     V     Spinach
 5      Bobby    M     Ham
 6      Bobby    F     Apple
 7      Bobby    V     Carrot`

I want to transpose it so that it will be sorted according to the Type, I want it to look like so

`Person      F       M        V
  Andy    Orange    Beef    Carrot
  Bobby   Apple     Ham     Carrot`

How can I manage to do this? Oh, and I'll also point some stuff in case you guys missed it:

1. The Types have no particular order, if you notice Andy's, the order is F M V V, but Bobby's is M F V.
2. Multiple instances of Type may occur, just like in Andy's case, notice the double V. But even so, I want it so that the only V that counts is the first one, thats why in the transposed table, the V is Carrot, because the Carrot occurred first (the Spinach is ignored).

I dont know if I ask too much, but even just the gist of the solution would be very helpful for me. The main point of my question is to ask how can I transpose such unsorted items, whilst paying attention to the 1st point. The 2nd point is important too, but I can wait or ask later if you guys dont feel like answering.

Thanks for reading, please share me your knowledge.

Comment: Will there always be just three different "Types", or could there be more?  Either way, I would create a Class object and read in the Person/Type/Name combo; give that a unique name such as Person|Type, add it to a collection with the unique name as a key, which would result in a collection consisting of unique PersonTypes, and only the first being retained.  Then put the result into an array that is wide enough to contain all the types; write it to a worksheet, and sort horizontally.  Read Chip Pearson's page on introduction to Classes to get started with that part of the routine.

Comment: If any answer helped, please consider marking as an answer, so others with the same problem can find the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The easisest/quickest way is to create a new column **before** the `TID` column which has this formula in it.

`=[Person]&"_"&[Type]`

For instance say your data started in column B, see screen shots (TID), then the first formula would be:

`=C2&"_"&D2` and will result in `Andy_F` being created. Copy this down for all the names you have.

You should have something like this:

```
NEW    TID  Person  Type    Name
Andy_F  1   Andy    F   Orange
Andy_M  2   Andy    M   Beef
Andy_V  3   Andy    V   Carrot
Andy_V  4   Andy    V   Spinach
Bobby_M 5   Bobby   M   Ham
Bobby_F 6   Bobby   F   Apple
Bobby_V 7   Bobby   V   Carrot
```

Next, set up a table like this (using copy unique items, if necessary), with unique names on the vertical and Types along the horizontal:

```
       F       M    V
Andy  [form]        
Bobby
```

Where `[form]` is a `vlookup` formula as in the screen shots below:

[image]

Resulting in the correct table for you, once the formula is copied to all cells in the new table:

[image]

`Vlookup` will grab the first item that matches its search critera, so multiple matches will be ignored.

The formula for Andy F in the table is `VLOOKUP($G2&"_"&H$1,$A$2:$E$8,5,0)`, with the data as in the screen shots.

A better way might be to use VBA, but this should do the trick.